# Mutiple Websites with different domain names on single magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I have installed one magento instance. I want to add 2 websites wholesale.com and retail.com.
Both the wholesale and retail websites are in a single magento. The products and catalogs are same for both the sites but prices will be different as per wholesale and retail websites.

When I will open a wholesale.com the customer should not see the price of the products. To see the price of products he/she need to login. And in retail.com customer can see the retail price of the product.

Also the customers will be different for both the sites. i.e. wholesale customers belongs to wholesale.com and retail customers belongs to retail.com.

I have tried some links but not able to do the same. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

1. For this setup, you should create 2 websites in your magento instantes. One for wholesale.com and another for retail.com.
2. Each website will have its own categories, and all products will have to be added to both websites and the categories in both websites.
3. To configure the visibility of the product prices, you will have to create or install an extension. It will have to be active for wholesale.com and inactive for retail.com.
4. You can determine how user accounts are shared over your magento installation: system wide or per website. You can find this setting under System - Configuration - Customer Configuration.
5. You can configure different prices for customer groups. In your case, I would create a customer group for the wholesale.com site. So, retail.com would show the default price. Under System - Configuration - Customer Configuration you can also set the Default Group for new accounts. Change your scope to wholesale.com and select the wholesale customer group.

I believe this should do it.

Comment: I got your idea but one thing i am not able to is how to open different websites in a browser like wholesale.com and retail.com.
How can I redirect to wholesale.com and retail.com separately.

Comment: You have to adjust the base-url for one of your sites. For example, if your default base-url is retail.com, then you have to adjust your base-url for wholesale.com.
Go to System - Configuration - General - Web, change the scope to your wholesale website and change the base-urls to wholesale.com.

Comment: I had tried this before but not able to redirect to wholesale.com or retail.com

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this. You also have to update the vhost settings on your server. You have to add the website code that should be run for each domain. For example: <br />  
`ServerName wholesale.com  
DocumentRoot    /path/to/magento/root/
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "wholesale_website_id"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"


ServerName retail.com
DocumentRoot    /path/to/magento/root/
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "retail_website_id"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website" `